# Sonata Block - add javascript block

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Is it possible to add a javascript block in a Sonata Block View like this ?

```
{% extends sonata_block.templates.block_base %}

{% block block %}

     <!-- html -->

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    // javascript code

{% endblock %}
```

I couldn't make it works in this way as javascript block doesn't exist in template block base but present in my layout.

Comment: Have you tried to put Javascript directly, without `{% block javascripts %}`?

Comment: Yes but this isn't what I want. I want to get the parent() of the javascript block of my layout, then add dynamically my js from the block view.
Sorry, I wasn't accurate about getting parent().

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible.. Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682968/adding-js-and-css-cleanly-from-included-twig-templates