# Add script to javascripts block inside a partial

Tags: javascript, twig, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have some UI elements that are used on different pages, so I put them on a separate template (partial)

inside this partial I want to have some js interactions, so I added a `{% block javascripts %}` with the wanted `script`

The thing is, as I just include this template on the different pages I need, it doesn't extends any layout/other template

Here is my partial

```
<div class="ui list inverted">
    {% for follow in follows.currentPageResults %}
        {{ include('backend/partials/follows_pagination_item.html.twig', {series:follow.series}) }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% if linkToPagination is defined and linkToPagination is same as(true) %}
    <div class="ui row">
        <div class="ui right floated">
            <a href="{{ url('admin_profile_follows', {page:1}) }}" class="ui tiny button teal">
                {{ 'admin.follows.go'|trans }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% if follows.haveToPaginate %}
        {{ pagerfanta(follows, 'semanticui_inverted', {'routeName': 'admin_profile_follows', 'routeParams':{'page':'page'}}) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/unfollow.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and I include it like this

```
{{ include('backend/partials/follows_pagination.html.twig', {linkToPagination:true}) }}
```

I need this parent (or equivalent function) because without this, the script is not added at the right place in DOM and I got the error `webpackJsonp is undefined` (my js files are built with webpackEncore)

Is there a way to correctly add my script in, the javascripts block ?

If not I guess I should not use the include function, but another one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding JS and CSS cleanly from included Twig templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682968/adding-js-and-css-cleanly-from-included-twig-templates)

Comment: Found different topics about template extension but not this one.
I'll try the solution.
Thanks a lot.